# Need help in handling woocommerce api timeout issue

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on an application where I'm using woocommerce API to create new orders like example below.

The issue is that sometimes after posting the data, the curl response times out. But the order is created as the order data is already sent with the request.

I need help to handle this timeout issue and delete the newly created record. Please note that when response timesout I'm not getting the newly created order ID so that I can delete it.

I'm using woocommerce API wrapper from https://packagist.org/packages/automattic/woocommerce

```
<?php
$data = [
'payment_method' => 'bacs',
'payment_method_title' => 'Direct Bank Transfer',
'set_paid' => true,
'billing' => [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'address_1' => '969 Market',
    'address_2' => '',
    'city' => 'San Francisco',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'postcode' => '94103',
    'country' => 'US',
    'email' => 'john.doe@example.com',
    'phone' => '(555) 555-5555'
],
'shipping' => [
    'first_name' => 'John',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'address_1' => '969 Market',
    'address_2' => '',
    'city' => 'San Francisco',
    'state' => 'CA',
    'postcode' => '94103',
    'country' => 'US'
],
'line_items' => [
    [
        'product_id' => 93,
        'quantity' => 2
    ],
    [
        'product_id' => 22,
        'variation_id' => 23,
        'quantity' => 1
    ]
],
'shipping_lines' => [
    [
        'method_id' => 'flat_rate',
        'method_title' => 'Flat Rate',
        'total' => 10
    ]
   ]
];
try{
  $order = $woocommerce->post('orders', $data);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log("Woocommerce order  " . $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL); // Error message.

    $lastResponse = $woocommerce->http->getResponse();
    $code = $lastResponse->getCode();

    error_log("Code " . $code . PHP_EOL);

    if ($code == 0) { //comes when timeout

    }       
}
}?>
```